# I want to change the div to a background image when i hover the other image in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {

  let bigImage = document.querySelector('#image');
  let u = previewPic.src;
  bigImage.style.backgroundImage = "url(u)";
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
```

when i hover on the class preview i want to change the background image  of my  id ="image".
but my cose is not working it is showing

[image: output when i hover the image]

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript code, you call `bigImage.style.backgroundImage = "url(u)";` which sets the div's backgroundImage style to `url(u)`. In order to have `u` be replaced with the content of the variable `u`, you can use a template literal like so `` bigImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${u})`; `` Using the backticks around your string allows you to put js code inside of the string which will be evalauted and put inside of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind variable either concatenating `"url(" + u +")"` or using template literals `url(${u})`, and also you need to add some width and height for div.

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {

  let bigImage = document.querySelector('#image');
  let u = previewPic.src;
  bigImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${u})`;
}

function unDo() {

}
```

```css
#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
```